# Top Command Output is Empty when run from cron

Tags: linux, shell, unix, cron

I was trying to redirect the TOP command output in the particular file in every 5 minutes with the below command.

```
top -b -n 1 > /var/tmp/TOP_USAGE.csv.$(date +"%I-%M-%p_%d-%m-%Y")

-rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Dec  9 17:20 TOP_USAGE.csv.05-20-PM_09-12-2015
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Dec  9 17:25 TOP_USAGE.csv.05-25-PM_09-12-2015
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Dec  9 17:30 TOP_USAGE.csv.05-30-PM_09-12-2015
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Dec  9 17:35 TOP_USAGE.csv.05-35-PM_09-12-2015
```

Hence i made a very small (1 line) shell script for this, so that i can run in every 5 minutes via cronjob.

Problem is when i run this script manually then i can see the output in the file, however when this script in running automatically, file is generating in every 5 minutes but there is no data (aka file is empty)

Can anyone please help me on this?

---

I now modified the script and still it's the same.

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)

/usr/bin/top -b -n 1 > /var/tmp/TOP_USAGE.csv.$(date +"%I-%M-%p_%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: The command works for me without changes. So the issue must be how you fire the command periodically. I assume you use a cron job for that? If so take care of the `PATH` environment variable so that the two commands (`top` and `date`) can actually be found by the process. Or simply use absolute paths.

Comment: @arkascha i am sorry..i am not bit clear with you answer.. Can you please help me to understand that. Can you please advise what is the exact changes you want me do to in command?

Comment: Well, if you execute a command on the command line, say `top` as an example, the system has to find out where that application actually is. For this a search is done over a number of folders, the first match is used. That search path is defined by an environment variable `PATH`. The content of that variable is defined by your account setup, so it can vary. The only way to not depend on that is to use the absolute path to the executables. On a typical GNU/Linux system that would be `/usr/bin/top` and `/usr/bin/date`. You can find out on your system by using the `which ` or `whereis` commands.

Comment: edit your Q to remind us what the `-b` option does for `top`. Is there anything else we should know, `uname -a` for  instance? Good luck!

Comment: @arkascha here is the output for 

uname -a
Linux MSX-GR 2.6.18.2-34.nx26-bigsmp #1 SMP Mon Nov 27 11:46:27 UTC 2006 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: In most Linux, `top` is `/usr/bin/top` and `date` is `/bin/date`. It's possible your default `PATH` when not set has `/bin` but doesn't have `/usr/bin`. Either you specify `/usr/bin/top -b -n 1 > /var/tmp/TOP_USAGE.csv.$(date +"%I-%M-%p_%d-%m-%Y")` in cron or you redirect `stderr` to a file to see the error message. In most cases the error message, when not redirected, is emailed to the owner of the cron job.

Comment: @alvits i tried the same and it is still not working. As you can see above i updated the change. Manually i am getting the output but when i do with cronjob file is empty. Can you please share your opinion?

Comment: Did you redirect `stderr` to a file? What was the error message?

Comment: Is it a copy paste error or is the shebang in your script wrong? It should be `#!/bin/sh` but you have `!/bin/sh`.

Comment: @albvits yes it is copy paste error.

Comment: 1. you still did not specify the path for the `date` command. I suggest you do that to be on the safe side. With that explicitly setting the `PATH` variable is obsolete too. 2. please post your exact cron job definition too, so the whole crontab, easiest. There might be some surprises in there. 3. try to substitute that `top` command by a simple `echo "hi there"` for a test. Does that work? 4. you should follow @alvits hint and also redirect the `stderr` output of the command: `/usr/bin/top -b -n 1 2>&1 > /var/tmp/TOP_USAGE.csv.$(date +"%I-%M-%p_%d-%m-%Y"), again, just for a temporary test.

Answer (score 7):

I met the same problem as you.

Top command with -b option must be added.Saving top output to variable before we use it.

the scripts are below

date >> /tmp/mysql-mem-moniter.log

MEM=`/usr/bin/top -b -n 1 -u mysql`

echo "$MEM" | grep mysql >> /tmp/mysql-mem-moniter.log

Comment: modify the bash script

Comment: worked for me - `-b` only required, no need to store variable.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the environment passed to your script from cron is too minimal. In particular, `PATH` may not be what you think it is (no profiles are read by scripts started from cron).

Place `PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)` at the start of your script, then run it with

```
/usr/bin/env -i /path/to/script
```

Once that works without error, it's ready for cron.

Comment: i tried the same and it is still not working for. Manually i am getting the output but when i do with cronjob file is empty. Can you please share your opinion?

Comment: @LiveCom You say you have modified your script. As shown it is broken: you must use `#!/bin/sh` instead of `!/bin/sh`. I've used a correct version here and it works just fine from cron. If all you get are zero sized files, more reasons could be: 1) /var/tmp is full, 2) Your disk space quota on /var/tmp is exceeded.

Comment: Yes i did..and i corrected the value..by mistake i typed incorrectly above. I checked other directory etc and i dont see any space related problem