# No output for top command by crontab

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am just a beginner for shell scripting and wrote a little script that run top command and clear the output leaving only cpu ram and swap values. If i run the script manually everything works fine but when i schedule the script to run every 5 minutes from /etc/crontab all run fine but the output of the top command doesn't appear in the log.

```
#############################

Sat Dec 12 02:05:00 GMT 2015

#############################
```

Below is the script. Can someone please help me to make it work?

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "#############################" >> /var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log
echo "" >> /var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log
/bin/date >> /var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log
/usr/bin/top -b -n 1 | /usr/bin/grep -E "Cpu|Mem|Swap|gis" >> /var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log
echo "" >> /var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log
echo "#############################" >> /var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log
```

Comment: I would not be surprised to find that `top` does not like being run without a terminal, and when it is run by `cron`, it won't have a terminal.  You can experiment with `sh -x the.script </dev/null 2>/dev/null` and see what appears in the top usage log file.  The `date` information should be there at least.  Also, you either should use `exec >> /var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log` before the first `echo` or you should use `{` on a line on its own before the first `echo` and `} >> /var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log` on a line on its own after the last `echo` and in either case lose all the intermediate `>>` redirections.

Comment: @jonathan Thanks for your reply. However i am sorry to say..i do not understand a reply little bit from you.. Is that possible if you can help to correct the script i pasted above by doing edit or something?

Comment: @LiveCom, you shouldn't ask the same question [twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34185717/top-command-output-is-empty-when-run-from-cron).

Comment: @Andrey actually the motive is same for both the question. However the reason i asked seperatly because i changed the script completely and still its giving the same error and i do not wanted to mix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235547/no-output-for-top-command-by-crontab#comment56214862_34235547), I said:

> You either should use exec >> /var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log before the first echo or you should use { on a line on its own before the first echo and } >> /var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log on a line on its own after the last echo and in either case lose all the intermediate >> redirections.

To which, [Live Com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4991529/live-com) [responded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235547/no-output-for-top-command-by-crontab#comment56214938_34235547):

> I do not understand the reply from you. Is it possible if you can help to correct the script I pasted above.

The I/O redirection in the original script is not wrong.  It is just verbose, and repetitive, and partially obscures what the script is doing.

There are at least three alternative redirection options.

#### Option 1 — Whole script redirection

```
#!/bin/sh
exec >> /var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log
echo "#############################"
echo ""
/bin/date
/usr/bin/top -b -n 1 | /usr/bin/grep -E "Cpu|Mem|Swap|gis"
echo ""
echo "#############################"
```

#### Option 2 — Part script redirection

```
#!/bin/sh
{
echo "#############################"
echo ""
/bin/date
/usr/bin/top -b -n 1 | /usr/bin/grep -E "Cpu|Mem|Swap|gis"
echo ""
echo "#############################"
} >> /var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log
```

Both options 1 and 2 avoid repetition.  Option 1 changes the status of standard output for the whole of the script that follows the `exec` (up until a countermanding `exec`, anyway).  Option 2 restricts the I/O redirection to the scope of the braces — which, in this example, is the whole of the script, but these can be used to good effect in part of a larger script.  Note that the braces must occur where a command could appear (roughly at the start of a line or after a semicolon — or pipe or ampersand).

#### Option 3 — Use a variable to avoid repeating the file name

If the repetition is kept, it would be better to create a variable for the file name so that much is not repeated:

```
#!/bin/sh
log="/var/tmp/TOPUSAGE.log"
echo "#############################"                        >> "$log"
echo ""                                                     >> "$log"
/bin/date                                                   >> "$log"
/usr/bin/top -b -n 1 | /usr/bin/grep -E "Cpu|Mem|Swap|gis"  >> "$log"
echo ""                                                     >> "$log"
echo "#############################"                        >> "$log"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help on this. However i tried all the 3 options and still i am getting only the date output in file.

#############################

Sat Dec 12 02:05:00 GMT 2015

#############################

Comment: Yes; my answer, such as it is, addresses the shell scripting issue I raised in my comment — which I took to be the confusing part (as I didn't think there could be much confusion about "maybe `top` doesn't work in a cron script"). I don't have a definitive answer for the behaviour of `top`, but it is a program that expects to have a terminal to display to and in a cron job, it does not have a terminal. Having said that, when run on Mac OS X (without the `-b` option since that isn't recognized), then I do get output in the file `x` when I run `top -n1 >x 2>/dev/null </dev/null`.

Comment: @LiveCom: Silly question time: where's `grep` on your machine?  On an Ubuntu system, where `top` supports the `-b` and `-n 1` options with a wholly different meaning from the Mac OS X variant, `grep` is in `/bin/grep` and not `/usr/bin/grep`.  Do you have an emails on the machine where you're running this?  Often `cron` sends the output from a script to the email of the user on whose behalf it is running the operation.